# Declaring a Phaser game collisionHandler callback with Node(?) syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, phaser-framework

I'm used to vanilla JavaScript syntax for building simple Phaser games, but I've been using this [Yeoman generator](https://github.com/julien/generator-phaser), which changes the syntax to something new that I'm not familiar with. I'm honestly not sure how to describe it, but basically instead of create the usual `create`, `update`, etc functions like this:

```
 function update() {
   game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite1, sprite2, collisionHandler, null, this);
}
```

It's defined like this:

```
exports.update = function(game) {
  game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite1, sprite2, collisionHandler, null, this);
}
```

The 3rd argument `collisionHandler` is a custom collision handler, which if I was using the first syntax style, I'd just create it using something like this:

```
function collisionHandler (sprite1, sprite2) {
  game.stage.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
}
```

I honestly don't know how to declare it using this new syntax i.e. the second example above e.g. `exports.update = function(game)`. I've tried various definitions similar to this for the `collisionHandler()` function, but they've all been wrong.

**QUESTIONS**

- Can someone tell me the correct way to declare that collision handler in the second syntax/style?
- Can someone share a great link that'll best explain this syntax?

I've got basic JavaScript coding down, but I have no experience with Node/Yeoman/etc, so I'm sure that's most of the problem :)

If you're not familiar with Phaser, here's some example code using https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/vertical-collision.

TIA!

Comment: Exporting in node is great! Here is a good article. https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: You can create an issue to enhance documentation for this generator on github https://github.com/julien/generator-phaser/issues